# ReactJS componentDidMount and Fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

Just started using ReactJS and JS, is there a way to return the JSON obtained from APIHelper.js to setState dairyList in App.jsx?

I think I'm not understanding something fundamental about React or JS or both. The dairyList state is never defined in Facebook React Dev Tools.

```
// App.jsx
export default React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      diaryList: []
    };
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      dairyList: APIHelper.fetchFood('Dairy'), // want this to have the JSON
    })
  },
  render: function() {
   ... 
  }


// APIHelper.js
var helpers = {
  fetchFood: function(category) {
    var url = 'http://api.awesomefoodstore.com/category/' + category

    fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(function(json) {
      console.log(category, json)
      return json
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('error', error)
    })
  }
}

module.exports = helpers;
```

Comment: Is your `APIHelper.js` file even syntactically correct? After you fix it, another thing: `APIHelper.fetchFood` is asynchronous.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks, just noticed the closing brace for fetchFood was after var url. Is there a better way to fetch the data, wait for the response and then go from there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `fetch` is async you'll need to do something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  APIHelper.fetchFood('Dairy').then((data) => {
    this.setState({dairyList: data});
  });
},
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for your answer it helped.

Comment: @Nikkawat Great! If there's nothing else you should click the checkmark next to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

It works! Made changes according to Jack's answer, added `.bind(this)` in componentDidMount() and changed `fetch(url)` to `return fetch (url)`

Thanks! I now see **State** > dairyList: Array[1041] with all the elements I need

```
// App.jsx
export default React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      diaryList: []
    };
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    APIHelper.fetchFood('Dairy').then((data) => {
      this.setState({dairyList: data});
    }.bind(this));
  },
  render: function() {
   ... 
  }


// APIHelper.js
var helpers = {
  fetchFood: function(category) {
    var url = 'http://api.awesomefoodstore.com/category/' + category

    return fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(function(json) {
      console.log(category, json)
      return json
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('error', error)
    })
  }
}

module.exports = helpers;
```

Comment: FWIW, You shouldn't need `.bind(this)` this automatically happens with the "fat arrow" (`() => {}` style.

Comment: Without `.bind(this)` I get an error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

Comment: That's interesting. The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and my experience say otherwise, but whatever works!