# Do i really need to use forceUpdate with fetch API and ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm using React and [fetch()](https://github.github.io/fetch/) to develop an UI and I ended up doing this:

```
getOperatorsList: function ( obj ) {
    fetch( 'http://x.x.x.x/operators.list',
        {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include'
        }
    ).then( function ( response ) {
            return response.json()
        } ).then( function ( json ) {
        if ( json.statusCode === 3 ) {
            cookieService.unsetCookie( 'sessId' );
        }
        obj.setState( { data: json }, () => obj.forceUpdate() );
    } ).catch( function ( ex ) {
        console.log( 'parsing failed', ex );
    } )

}
```

This is called in my component Operators that looks like this

```
var Operators = React.createClass( {

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            data: [{ "data": "Loading" }]
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function () {
        operatorsService.getOperatorsList( this );
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Row >
                    <Col>
                        <DataTablesCustom data={this.state.data} />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
         );
     }
});
```

I already had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755092/reactjs-componentdidmount-and-fetch-api), and the code doesn't work for me.

This works fine but do I really need to use `forceUpdate()` or do I have a way to make the code "cleaner" ?

EDIT: there was a `setState` that looked like this `this.setState({stuff: stuff}, this.function()});` in a child component. I was able to remove `forceUpdate()` after changing the `setState` to `this.setState({stuff: stuff}, () => this.function()});`.

Comment: It works without ?

Comment: Without it, the data i want is not showing when the page loads.

Comment: So you have your answer, you must use it ;) (this code looks clear for me)

Comment: This is mostly about how the ReactJS doc says that forceUpdate() should be avoided but i wanted another point of view. thanks :)

Comment: @Steeve Pitis that code does not look clean at all. Also, he doesn't really have to call ```forceUpdate``` at all if he restructure his code a bit better.

Comment: No. `setState` _should_ be enough for the task. But why are you passing `this` to `getOperatorsList`? Why don't you just return the promise for use in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: When i first tried using `then()` as @fabio.sussetto did, it didn't work, so i decided to just call `setState` directly in the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your code to work, you can try to do this in the service:

```
obj.setState.bind(obj)( { data: json });
```

However, there is no need to pass the component object to your service. Arguably, that's not such a good idea as you're just coupling things when it's not needed. Let the component call your service and then decide what to do with the data:

```
 getOperatorsList: function () {
    return fetch( 'http://x.x.x.x/operators.list', {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include'
    }).then( function ( response ) {
        return response.json()
    }).then( function ( json ) {
        if (json.statusCode === 3 ) {
            cookieService.unsetCookie( 'sessId' );
        }
        return json;
    }).catch( function ( ex ) {
      console.log( 'parsing failed', ex );
    })

}
```

Then in your component:

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    operatorsService.getOperatorsList()
    .then(function (json) {
       this.setState({ data: json });
    }.bind(this))
}
```

Comment: You forgot to return the promise in `getOperatorsList`

Comment: I'm getting 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined' and the question i quoted did this plus added a return before fetch() but this doesn't work either. i'm getting the same behaviour as before.

Comment: @Harmeko sorry, I just forgot to return the promises, I updated getOperatorsList with the `return` statement.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I really don't understand what's wrong. 
And there's more, when i tried to `console.log(this);` inside your `then()` and look at the state, there's data in it but not if i `console.log(this.state.data)`.

Comment: @Harmeko from the React docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html  "setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value." That's why console.log(this.state) doesn't show you the data. If it still doesn't work, please try to debug/ ```console.log(this.state.data)``` in ```render``` and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't have anything to do with my problem, thanks.